# full text queries using "or" in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Summary of question:

In each Parse object, I have a list of keywords relevant to that object as an NSArray of NSString. I want the user to be able to enter one or more words and find all objects which have at least one of these words in their keyword list. As this will be a search across the entire database, it needs to be as efficient as possible.

Longer version/background:

I am building an ios objective-c app which allows the creation and storage of vector drawings. These are indexed by two searchable fields. There is an optional "tag" field which must be an exact match - tags might be "small", "medium" or "large". There is also a description field the user enters when they save the drawing, such as "drawing of a red car" or "my little blue automobile".

Following suggestions on the web, I also store the words in the description as an NSArray of NSString in Parse, all in lower case with stop words removed, called "keywords" so a typical PFObject might be

tag:"small";
description:"My little Blue automobile";
keywords:"little", "blue", "automobile"

I want the user to be able to search for all records containing the words "car" **or** "automobile". They should also be able to optionally specify the contents of the tag field (eg "small") which is an "and" - it will find all records with "car" or "automobile" in the description **and** have "small" in the tag field.

I can do searches against the description field using [query whereKey:@"description" containsString:@"car"] and then do the same for containsString:@"automobile" and then combine the results. This works, but has two problems. Firstly it can't be an indexed search as we are searching for a string inside a string. Secondly it requires me to manually merge the results. I am hoping the keyword field will allow more intelligent queries.

How do I construct the object's fields and the user queries to make this as efficient as possible? Any other suggestions?

Thanks ...

Comment: How are you "manually merging the results"?

Comment: I merge the list two results using the ObjectID field, so each ObjectID appears only once. Somebody might have both "car" and "automobile" in their description field, and I don't want that drawing to appear twice in the list of matching objects. The merge itself isn't a problem, it is that I may have to undertake 5 different searches if they enter 5 search words, and I assume each search is highly inefficient because the server has to retrieve every description field to see if it contains a matching substring - the words in the description aren't indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from your question how you're currently combining your queries, but Parse has a built in way of doing so using [`orQueryWithSubqueries:`](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS), ex:

```
[query1 whereKey:@"description" containsString:@"car"];
[query2 whereKey:@"description" containsString:@"automobile"];
PFQuery *combinedQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1,query2]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's heaps better than what I am doing (which was merging the results manually)! But I am still worried about the efficiency of containsString, as I can't see how the words in "description" can be database indexes. Tell me that it is efficient anyway, or it shouldn't be a problem in practice, or that there is no more efficient way of doing it, and I will gladly accept your answer. In the mean time thankyou for a way better solution than what I currently have.

Comment: @PeterWebb Yes, containsString: is a slower operation than whereKey:equals: so I recommend searching your keyword array instead.